# Remove Last Character in th using ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

How to remove last character inside of table header using javascript/ajax?

**Example table:**

| Product | Price X |
| --- | --- |
| First | 1000 |
| Second | 2000 |

What I want to reach is remove the **X** on Price X column header with some button, I've use slice before but not working.

How I supposed to do?

Comment: To get the HTML ***after*** the table is loaded, F12 and click "Elements" tab for Chrome and "Inspector" tab  for Firefox. Post the HTML as a [mcve].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

try this function:

```
function noLastCharaceter(txt) {
  return txt.substr(0, txt.length - 1);
}
```

If you are asking, how to use it, so if your table id is "tableId", try this:

```
var table = document.getElementById("tableId"); 
var headers = table.getElementsByTagName("TH"); // list of "th" elements
headers[1].innerHTML = noLastCharacter(headers[1].innerHTML); // replace content of second column
```

Comment: Why would the HTML element `th` be uppercase?

Comment: @Cjmarkham [it doesn't matter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)... _"When called on an HTML element in an HTML document, `getElementsByTagName` lower-cases the argument before searching for it"_

Comment: ... and when you ask for the `el.tagName` you will also get it in uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very similar script that demonstrates the use of a suitable selector and a simple `.slice()` operation on the `.textContent` of the `<th>` element (please note that `String.prototype.substr()` is deprecated).

```js
const th=document.querySelector("#myTable th:last-child");
th.textContent=th.textContent.slice(0,-2)
```

```html
<table id="myTable"><thead><tr><th>Product</th><th>Price X</th><tr></thead><tbody>
<tr><td>First</td><td>1000</td></tr>
<tr><td>Second</td><td>2000</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```